# ¿Cómo indico a un formulario cual es siguiente formulario que quiero abrir?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de registro de inasistencia de personal y me surgió el problema que necesito indicarle a un formulario, en donde se lista cierta entidad, el siguiente formulario que se debe abrir despues de haberla sido elegida.

Mi duda es, mas que nada, de implementación y diseño ya que tengo una idea de como aplicarla pero tengo mis dudas con respecto si es mantenible.
Tengo la posibilidad de usar un enumerado para indicar que el siguiente formulario o pasar el tipo de formulario o la instancia del formulario por constructor. Capaz exista otra manera mas elegante de hacerlo pero la desconozco.

No elegí instanciar los formularios en serie por una cuestión de perfomance, mantenibilidad y extensibilidad.

Para orientarlos un poco mas, flujo de trabajo seria el siguiente:

**frmPrincipal.cs**:

Es la pantalla principal para arrancar y tiene esta 2 opciones.

```
private void tsmiDatosPersonal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmPersonalListado frm = new frmPersonalListado();
    frm.ShowDialog(this);
}

private void tsmiInasistenciasPersonal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmPersonalListado frm = new frmPersonalListado();
    frm.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

**frmPersonalListado.cs**:

Es donde se listan el personal del establecimiento y luego selecciono uno de la lista y abre el siguiente formulario.

```
public frmPersonalListado()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _personalNegocio = new PersonalNegocio();
    _inasistenciaNegocio = new Lazy<InasistenciaNegocio>();
}

public frmPersonalListado(Form formularioObjetivo) 
    : this()
{
    _formularioObjetivo = formularioObjetivo;
}

private void tsbVerPersonal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Aplicacion.Entidades.Personal personalSeleccionado = lvPersonal.SelectedItems[0].Tag as Aplicacion.Entidades.Personal;
    frmPersonalCRUD frm = new frmPersonalCRUD(ModoFormulario.Ver, personalSeleccionado); // <<< Aca deberia instanciar el formulario correcto elegido desde el menú.
    frm.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

El flujo es parecido al de un *workflow* con la cual hay un comportamiento que se define al principio: Si se abre X o Y formulario final.

### Edición 1:

Como cuesta interpretar la idea, les dejo una imagen que muestra el flujo de trabajo que siguen los formularios que trabajo.

El real problema es cual es el diseño e implementación correcta para hacer que formulario inicial le indique al formulario siguiente que comportamiento debe tener para que abra alguno de los últimos formularios.

[image: Descripción del flujo]

### Edición 2:

El siguiente [*commit*](https://github.com/drielnox/escuela-simple/commit/b9661ae4dfd5143f129decf6363d61bb577ba5fc) del código demuestra el *code smell* que menciono anteriormente.

Mi idea es que, cada vez que instancio `frmPersonalListado`, pase por constructor el comportamiento que tiene que tener cuando selecciono un personal de lista.
Este comportamiento es el de instanciar el siguiente formulario, pasando como parámetro al constructor, el personal elegido de la lista.

```
private void tsbPersonalInasistencias(object sender, EventArgs event)
{
    var frm = new frmPersonalListado(x => {
        var frm2 = new frmCrudPersonal(); // <<< Como inyecto el personal aca?
        frm2.ShowDialog(this) // <<< Ese this podria ser frm?
    });
    frm.ShowDialog(this);
}

public frmPersonalListado(Func<Personal, void> nextForm)
{
    _func = nextForm;
}

private void btnSeleccionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs event)
{
    var personal = ObtenerPersonalSeleccionado();
    _func(personal); // Magicamente, deberia instanciar el form con el personal seleccionado.
}
```

Pero el código de arriba es una idea que no compila.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. cual es especificamente el problema?

Comment: @gbianchi ahí aclare un poco mas el problema.

Comment: Ya tienes la implementación, cierto? ¿Cual es el problema con ella?

Comment: @Braiam ya lo tengo implementado usando un enum pero no me gusto. Lo podes ver [acá](https://github.com/drielnox/escuela-simple/blob/master/src/Presentaci%C3%B3n/Interfaz%20de%20Usuario/EscuelaSimple/frmPrincipal.cs#L63)

Comment: Por que no te gusta?

Comment: @Braiam te puede sonar subjetivo pero veo un _code smell_ ahí. Usar enumerados para ese tipo de cosas no me parece correcto. Lo único que se es que tengo una vaga idea de que inyecta el comportamiento por el constructor con un `Func<>` o un `Action<>` para abrir el siguiente formulario.

Comment: Edita la pregunta, agrega el codigo que te molesta y explica por que. No somos adivinos :).

Comment: @Braiam gracias. Ahora entiendo como hacer, correctamente, preguntas en SOes :)

Comment: Cambia el Func<Personal, void> a Action<Personal> y usa el 'x' de la lambda dentro como si fuera el  parámetro que pasas a _func(). No lo pongo como respuesta que estoy en el móvil y no puedo formatearla bien

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para "actualizarla"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Editado

Si quieres ir mediante callbacks, para que el código que has puesto te compile, debes hacer algo similar a esto:

En el form que lo llama:

```
private void tsbPersonalInasistencias(object sender, EventArgs event)
{
    var frm = new frmPersonalListado(x => {
        var frm2 = new frmCrudPersonal(x); // <-- nota que usamos el parametro de la lambda (x)
        frm2.ShowDialog(this)
    });
    frm.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

En frmPersonalListado:

```
private Action<Personal> _func;

public frmPersonalListado(Action<Personal> nextForm)
{
    _func = nextForm;
}

private void btnSeleccionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs event)
{
    var personal = ObtenerPersonalSeleccionado();
    _func(personal); // El 'x' de la lambda de arriba se convierte en "personal"
}
```

Dicho esto, esta opción no es ni mejor, ni más fácil de mantener que la otra. Lo único que estás haciendo es delegar el código a un callback, pero al final escribes el mismo código que si lo hicieras a mano.

Como digo, hay mil formas de hacerlo: podrías pasar el tipo y usar el `Activator` para crear la instancia, o directamente pasar el tipo siguiente en un genérico del form (aunque perderías el diseñador de WinForms a menos que uses algunos trucos). También tus formularios destino podrían implementar algún interfaz que tuviera alguna función `EligePersonal` o algo similar, y pasarle el tipo de interfaz al selector de personal (como inyección de dependencias, pero no automática, al ser variable según parámetros).

En cualquier caso, creo que estás empezando la casa por el tejado: si tu idea es tener código mantenible y manejable, empieza por dejar de escribir lógica de negocio en el form y empieza a usar algún patrón de diseño (el que te resulte más cómodo, aunque MVP es el que se suele aplicar a WinForms, también puedes usar MVVM o MVC)... y si no quieres usar ninguno de estos, puedes inventarte el tuyo, pero escribir la lógica de lo que hacen las funciones en los propios eventos (fuera de modificar la propia vista) es ya de por sí poco mantenible, y deberías empezar por ahí.

Lo que quieres hacer puedes cambiarlo de sitio, pero al final, de alguna manera tienes que escribir el código (o el tipo de form al menos) que necesitas. Sea en `Actions`, sea mediante interfaces, sea pasando tipos y creándolos con el `Activator`, o sea inyectando dependencias.

**ESE** no es el problema de mantenibilidad.

Y lo más lógico en tu caso (sea un form, o 100, da igual), es que si un formulario necesita una persona seleccionada, tenga dos opciones: lo llamas con esa persona (mediante una función, en el constructor, donde quieras), o bien lo llamas sin esa persona: en ese caso, ese formulario (y no el "llamante") debería ser el encargado de sacarte la ventana de selección de personal.

Eso es lo "conceptualmente" lógico, y no lo otro.

---

### Pregunta Antigua

*Ya no aplica después de la edición de la pregunta*

Hombre, no entiendo muy muy bien la pregunta, pero si la idea es (si yo no la he entendido mal), que cuando seleccionas una opción, primero se abre un formulario dejándote elegir al personal (este es común sin importar la opción que elijas), y después el formulario se abre con el dato de la persona que has elegido...

Bueno, hay mil maneras de implementarlo, pero viendo que estás usando `ShowDialog` para todo y que la aplicación sigue un flujo fijo bloqueando el resto...

Pues yo invertiría el orden de acciones, y tendría un selector de "personal" en una clase de ayuda.

Siguiendo tu ejemplo:

`frmPersonalListado.cs`

```
// Pasamos el constructor a privado:
private frmPersonalListado()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _personalNegocio = new PersonalNegocio();
    _inasistenciaNegocio = new Lazy<InasistenciaNegocio>();
}

private Aplicacion.Entidades.Personal _personaSeleccionada = null;

public static Aplicacion.Entidades.Personal SeleccionaPersonal()
{
  using(var frm = new frmPersonalListado())
  {
    var dr = frm.ShowDialog(); // podemos pasar el owner como parametro si es importante
    if(dr == DialogResult.Ok)
      return frm._personaSeleccionada;
    return null;
  }
}

private void tsbVerPersonal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _personalSeleccionada = lvPersonal.SelectedItems[0].Tag as Aplicacion.Entidades.Personal;
  this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Y en el form principal, donde antes hacias el `ShowDialog` de `frmPersonalListado`, ahora haces:

```
private void tsmiDatosPersonal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var persona = frmPersonalListado.SeleccionaPersonal();
    if(persona != null)
    {
       using(var frm = new frmPersonalCRUD(ModoFormulario.Ver, persona))
       {
         frm.ShowDialog(this);
       }
    }
}

private void tsmiInasistenciasPersonal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var persona = frmPersonalListado.SeleccionaPersonal();
    if(persona != null)
    {
       using(var frm = new frmElOtroTipoDeFormulario(ModoFormulario.Ver, persona))
       {
         frm.ShowDialog(this);
       }
    }
}
```

Esta sería la forma más sencilla y más "sana" según lo que yo he entendido de las especificaciones.

Si el selector de personal se va a llamar desde otros sitios, quizá merecería la pena meterlo en cada uno de esos formularios (en el evento `Load` o similar).

De ahí, y en cuanto a mantenibilidad, te puedes liar lo que quieras... desde inyectar (haciendo un interfaz y usando DI) el formulario de seleccion de personal al form destino, hasta lo que te apetezca. Esta solución que te doy es muy básica pero también lo parece el código que nos enseñas.

*Disclaimer: he escrito el código rápido y sin comprobarlo, probablemente haya errores de sintaxis*

Comment: nos estamos entendiendo pero no es lo que deseo realmente. El codigo que me mostras no me es "mantenible". Hoy en dia son dos formularios que usan un mismo listado. El dia de mañana van a ser mas. Mi problema es mas una cuestión de diseño de software que de implementación.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es una solución de diseño para implementarte el flujo de trabajo de tu aplicación dependiendo de estados... es una cuestión larga y dependería mucho de los requisitos de la aplicación.

Hay aplicaciones brutales hechas sólo para definir flujos de estados.

Depende de la genericidad y complejidad que necesites hay unas soluciones u otras. No creo que esto sea algo contestable en `StackOverflow`. Es una pregunta muy amplia y con un abanico de respuestas "opinables" enorme.

Pero vamos, si quieres googlear, yo empezaría por "maquina de estados"

Comment: si. En eso te tengo que decir que tenes la razón. Hablar sobre cuestiones de diseño no es propio para StackOverflow. Esta pregunta esta mas orientada para Programmers.

Answer (score 3):

Si no quieres que tu proyecto se convierta en un caos inmantenible en cuanto crezca un poco, deberías separar la lógica de la presentación. Una buena forma de conseguir esto en Windows Forms es usar [el patrón Modelo-Vista-Presentador](http://theartoftheleftfoot.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/el-patron-modelo-vista-presentador-mvp.html). Copiado de ese enlace:

> Básicamente este patrón consiste en 3 componentes:
>
> - La vista. Compuesta de las ventanas y controles que forman la interfaz de usuario de la aplicación.
> - El modelo. Que es donde se lleva a cabo toda la lógica de negocio.
> - El presentador. Escucha los eventos que se producen en la vista y ejecuta las acciones necesarias a través del modelo. Además puede
>     tener acceso a las vistas a través de las interfaces que la vista debe
>     implementar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**[Aquí tienes una solución de ejemplo en GitHub](https://github.com/Konamiman/MvpWinformsApp)** construida a partir del ejemplo con tres formularios que muestras en tu pregunta. A continuación explico los puntos más significativos del proyecto.

- En primer lugar creamos las clases que representan **el modelo** que queremos mostrar/editar en el interfaz de usuario.

Incluimos también un repositorio para datos, con su correspondiente interfaz:

```
class PersonaResumida
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string Dni { get; set; }
}

//Podría heredar de PersonaResumida
class PersonaEnDetalle
{
    public string InformacionAdicional { get; set; }
}

class Inasistencia
{
    public string Motivo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Desde { get; set; }
    public DateTime Hasta { get; set; }
}

interface IRepositorioDePersonal
{
    IEnumerable<PersonaResumida> ObtenerPersonas();
    PersonaEnDetalle ObtenerPersona(string dni);
    IEnumerable<Inasistencia> ObtenerInasistencias(string dni);
}
```

- A continuación creamos **interfaces para las vistas**. Estos interfaces modelan el **comportamiento externo** (la interacción con el resto de la aplicación) de las vistas.

También creamos un interfaz base con funcionalidad común:

```
interface IElementoDeUI
{
    void Cerrar();
    event EventHandler CierreSolicitado;
}

interface IListadoDePersonalUI : IElementoDeUI
{
    void EstablecerPersonas(IEnumerable<PersonaResumida> personas);
    event EventHandler<PersonaSeleccionadaEventArgs> PersonaSeleccionada;
}

interface IDatosDePersonalUI : IElementoDeUI
{
    void EstablecerPersona(PersonaEnDetalle persona);
}

interface IInasistenciasDePersonalUI : IElementoDeUI
{
    void EstablecerInasistencias(IEnumerable<Inasistencia> personas);
}
```

Nótese como tenemos dos tipos de interacciones: hacia la vista (establecemos los datos a mostrar) y desde la vista (eventos generados, en este caso, únicamente por el usuario).

- Creamos **las vistas** (los formularios), que implementan los interfaces.

También en este caso creamos una clase base que implementará la interfaz común:

```
public partial class FormBase : Form, IElementoDeUI
{
    public event EventHandler CierreSolicitado;

    protected void EmitirCierreSolicitado()
    {
        CierreSolicitado(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void Cerrar()
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    //Hay más código, sólo se muestra aquí lo importante
}

public partial class frmListadoDePersonal : FormBase, IListadoDePersonalUI
{
    public event EventHandler<PersonaSeleccionadaEventArgs> PersonaSeleccionada;

    public void EstablecerPersonas(IEnumerable<PersonaResumida> personas)
    {
        gridPersonas.DataSource = personas;
    }

    private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmitirCierreSolicitado();
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dni = (gridPersonas.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as PersonaResumida).Dni;
        PersonaSeleccionada(this, new PersonaSeleccionadaEventArgs {DniSeleccionado = dni});
    }

    //Hay más código, sólo se muestra aquí lo importante
}

//Hay más vistas, omitidas por brevedad
```

- Necesitamos una **factoría de vistas**, que se encargue de generar las instancias de los formularios a partir de su interfaz, y de alguna otra operación auxiliar con el motor de UI.

Esta sería la interfaz de la factoría, la implementación del proyecto de ejemplo usa `Activator.CreateInstance` pero eso ahora es irrelevante:

```
interface IFactoriaDeUI
{
    T ObtenerInstanciaDe<T>() where T : class, IElementoDeUI;
    void Mostrar<T>(T elementoDeUI) where T : class, IElementoDeUI;
}
```

- Y finalmente tenemos el **presentador**, que se encarga de coordinar la creación, cierre e interacción entre las vistas.

A continuación un fragmento del código del presentador. ¡Fíjate que no tiene ninguna dependencia con Windows Forms!

```
class Presentador
{
    private readonly IVentanaPrincipalUI ventanaPrincipal;
    private readonly IFactoriaDeUI factoriaDeUi;
    private readonly IRepositorioDePersonal repositorioDePersonal;

    private string solicitud; //Tipo string para simplificar, se podría usar un enum

    public Presentador(
        IVentanaPrincipalUI ventanaPrincipal, 
        IFactoriaDeUI factoriaDeUi, 
        IRepositorioDePersonal repositorioDePersonal)
    {
        this.ventanaPrincipal = ventanaPrincipal;
        this.factoriaDeUi = factoriaDeUi;
        this.repositorioDePersonal = repositorioDePersonal;

        ventanaPrincipal.DatosSolicitados += VentanaPrincipal_DatosSolicitados;
        ventanaPrincipal.InasistenciasSolicitadas += VentanaPrincipal_InasistenciasSolicitadas;
    }

    private void VentanaPrincipal_DatosSolicitados(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        solicitud = "datos";
        MostrarListadoDeUsuarios();
    }

    private void VentanaPrincipal_InasistenciasSolicitadas(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        solicitud = "inasistencias";
        MostrarListadoDeUsuarios();
    }

    private void MostrarListadoDeUsuarios()
    {
        var usuarios = repositorioDePersonal.ObtenerPersonas();
        var uiParaListado = factoriaDeUI.ObtenerInstanciaDe<IListadoDePersonalUI>();
        uiParaListado.EstablecerPersonas(usuarios);

        uiParaListado.CierreSolicitado += (sender, args) => { (sender as IElementoDeUI).Cerrar(); };
        uiParaListado.PersonaSeleccionada += UiParaListado_PersonaSeleccionada;

        factoriaDeUi.Mostrar(uiParaListado);
    }

    //UiParaListado_PersonaSeleccionada muestra la vista de detalles
    //o la de inasistencias, dependiendo del valor de "solicitud"
}
```

Como guinda, así es como se inicia la aplicación. En una aplicación real se usaría algún contenedor de inyección de dependencias:

```
static void Main()
{
    var formPrincipal = new frmMain();
    var factoriaDeUI = new FactoriaDeUI(formPrincipal);
    var repositorio = new RepositorioDePersonal();
    presentador = new Presentador(formPrincipal, factoriaDeUI, repositorio);

    Application.Run(formPrincipal);
}
```

#### Puntos interesantes

- Al ser independiente de la tecnología de interfaz de usuario, el presentador es completamente *unit-testable*.
- ...y por la misma razón, si quisieras cambiar dicha tecnología en el futuro (por ejemplo, usar WPF) podrías reutilizar el presentador (y también las clases del modelo y los interfaces de las vistas).
- Las propias vistas pueden tener algo de lógica interna que no afecte al funcionamiento de la aplicación en conjunto. Por ejemplo, en el listado de personal, el código que se encarga de deshabilitar el botón "Continuar" si no hay ninguna persona seleccionada puede ser parte del *code-behind* del formulario. **Pero si quieres pruebas unitarias para esto, deberás controlarlo desde el presentador.** Es tu decisión.
- A medida que crezca la aplicación probablemente necesitarás crear una clase que se encargue de la *lógica de negocio* y dejar el presentador únicamente para la *lógica de presentación*.

Y básicamente eso es todo. Espero que esta parrafada te sea de ayuda.

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Sigo sin entender muy bien lo que quieres, pero si quieres tener un "creador" de formularios, seria bueno que implementaras un patrón de diseño de la categoría de creación, para separar la lógica de creación de formularios de la lógica que escoja el formulario que debería seguir, y en la lógica de creación de formularios manejas el tema de la instanciación y demás cosas. Te recomiendo leer el patrón de Diseño [Factory Method](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Method_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)), esto para asegurarte mantenibilidad en el código.

> En diseño de software, el patrón de diseño Factory Method consiste en utilizar una clase constructora (al estilo del Abstract Factory) abstracta con unos cuantos métodos definidos y otro(s) abstracto(s): el dedicado a la construcción de objetos de un subtipo de un tipo determinado.